# How to convert from pandas.DatetimeIndex to numpy.datetime64?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

How to convert from `pandas.DatetimeIndex` to `numpy.datetime64`?

I get:

```
>>> type(df.index.to_datetime())
Out[56]: pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

Is it safe to do `numpy.array(datetimeindex,dtype=numpy.datetime64)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The data inside *is* of `datetime64` dtype (`datetime64[ns]` to be precise). Just take the `values` attribute of the index. Note it will be nanosecond unit.

Comment: is this still true with pandas 0.10.1? `pd.date_range("20120101", "20120102").values` yields `array([1970-01-16 224:00:00, 1970-01-16 248:00:00], dtype=datetime64[ns])`, which is not correct.

Answer (score 9):

I would do this:-

```
new_array = np.array(df.index.to_pydatetime(), dtype=numpy.datetime64)
```

using the `to_pydatetime()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If your index is supposed to be the date or datetime values, you can convert it to a DatetimeIndex

```
   df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```