# pd.Timestamp versus np.datetime64: are they interchangeable for selected uses?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, datetime

This question is motivated by [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49719901/9209546) to a [question on improving performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719627/boolean-mask-from-pandas-datetime-index-using-loc-accessor) when performing comparisons with `DatetimeIndex` in `pandas`.

The solution converts the `DatetimeIndex` to a `numpy` array via `df.index.values` and compares the array to a `np.datetime64` object. This appears to be the most efficient way to retrieve the Boolean array from this comparison.

The feedback on this question from one of the developers of `pandas` was: "These are not the same generally. Offering up a numpy solution is often a special case and not recommended."

My questions are:

1. Are they interchangeable for a subset of operations? I appreciate
   `DatetimeIndex` offers more functionality, but I require only basic functionality such as slicing and indexing.
2. Are there any documented differences in *result* for operations that are translatable to `numpy`?

In my research, I found some posts which mention "not always compatible" - but none of them seem to have any conclusive references / documentation, or specify why/when generally they are incompatible. Many other posts use the `numpy` representation without comment.

- [Pandas DatetimeIndex indexing dtype: datetime64 vs Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676418/pandas-datetimeindex-indexing-dtype-datetime64-vs-timestamp)
- [How to convert from pandas.DatetimeIndex to numpy.datetime64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227865/how-to-convert-from-pandas-datetimeindex-to-numpy-datetime64)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my opinion, you should always prefer using a `Timestamp` - it can easily transform back into a numpy datetime in the case it is needed.

`numpy.datetime64` is essentially a thin wrapper for `int64`.  It has almost no date/time specific functionality.

`pd.Timestamp` is a wrapper around a `numpy.datetime64`.  It is backed by the same int64 value, but supports the entire `datetime.datetime` interface, along with useful pandas-specific functionality.

The in-array representation of these two is identical - it is a contigous array of int64s.  `pd.Timestamp` is a scalar box that makes working with individual values easier.

Going back to the linked answer, you could write it like this, which is shorter and happens to be faster.

```
%timeit (df.index.values >= pd.Timestamp('2011-01-02').to_datetime64()) & \
        (df.index.values < pd.Timestamp('2011-01-03').to_datetime64())
192 µs ± 6.78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. But I'm still confused. Typically, the route to optimise `pandas` is to drop down to `numpy` [and then maybe `numba` or `cython`]. Is there a specific reason this is inadvisable specifically for `pd.Timestamp`?

Comment: That advice while it often works in practice, is very simplistic. Numpy isn't inherently faster than pandas, it's more the case the pandas often uses numpy internally, so if you know exactly what you want you  can elide some overhead. In this case, the array operation is identical either way,  just a faster scalar construction.

Comment: How do you convert an entire column into `pd.Timestamp`, since `pd.to_datetime()` returns datetime64?