# how to change dd-mm-yyyy date format to yyyy-dd-mm in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How to change dd-mm-yyyy date format to yyyy-dd-mm in pandas. I have a datefield which is already in dd-mm-yyyy format but when I try

```
df[('date')] = pd.to_datetime(df[('date')]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

it gives output a yyyy-dd-mm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you needed.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("dates.csv")

df

   id        date
0   1  25/06/2018
1   2  14-11-2005
2   3  03/10/2010
3   4  13-08-2008
4   5  05-05-2005
```

Here no need to specify the format as you have tried.

```
df['date'] =pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df

 id       date
0   1 2018-06-25
1   2 2005-11-14
2   3 2010-03-10
3   4 2008-08-13
4   5 2005-05-05
```

Comment: Hi,even if I don't specify it gives me result in yyyy-mm-dd... Does it matter if the earlier date format is dd/mm/yyyy delimiter is (/) rather than (-) ??

Comment: Can you please specify in which format you wanted it to be? Ex:- `yyyy-mm-dd` (or) `yyyy/mm/dd` (or) `dd-mm-yyyy` (or) `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: My date format is dd/mm/yyyy but i want it in yyyy-mm-dd format.. But when i do pd.datetime it gives me result as yyyy-dd-mm

Comment: I've tested with `dd/mm/yyyy` format and the same function is giving me in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, not in `yyyy-dd-mm` format.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `datetime` series data do **not** have an inherent string format.

`datetime` values are stored internally as integers. For more details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758140/9209546). String representations are just that, **representations**. For example, when you use the `print` command, a specific string representation is used so that data is displayed in a human-readable way.

For most purposes, you should not worry about the representation. If you need a format different to the default representation, i.e. "YYYY-MM-DD", you can use [`pd.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and specify a string format. For this [Python's `strftime` directives](http://strftime.org/) is a useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')#specify input format '%d-%m-%Y' and output format '%Y-%m-%d' or change output as desired i.e. %d/%m/%Y to give dd/mm/yyyy
```