# Slicing and editiing date in .csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

New to python,

Trying to sort a dataset ready for comparison using pandas however I need to edit certain aspects before a comparison is possible. There is an 'A' before each of my dates which needs to be removed. In addition to this, the format of the date itself is YYYYDDD which needs to be change to DD/MM/YYYY or my other dataset needs to be changed to YYYYDDD, whichever is easiest.

My attempt to remove the 'A' is as follows, I have no idea where to even begin in relation to modifying the date apart from perhaps using the library 'datetime'.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

csv = '/home/student/Desktop/Ben_Folder/AirQuality/Test/2002_DDV.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(csv)
test = df(columns='Date'[1:7])

test.to_csv('Test.csv', header=['Date', 'AOD'])
```

Example of dataset as follows:

```
       Date  AOT
0  A2002185  0.0
1  A2002185  0.0
2  A2002185  0.0
3  A2002185  0.0
4  A2002185  0.0
```

Comment: provide a sample data set (df.head()), then it would be easy to answer

Comment: The dataset does have variables that go from 001 to 365, please see MODIS naming methods: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates in Pandas are [stored as integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758140/9209546). Anything *else* you see is just a string representation of those integers. Once you are aware of this, you will appreciate the benefit of converting to `datetime` objects.

Here you can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), which allows you to specify your format:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='A%Y%j')

print(df)

        Date  AOT
0 2002-07-04  0.0
1 2002-07-04  0.0
2 2002-07-04  0.0
3 2002-07-04  0.0
4 2002-07-04  0.0
```

[Python's `strftime` directives](http://strftime.org/) is a useful resource to building custom string formats.

Comment: So if I wished to reformat to DDMMYYYY it would be %d%m%Y? How would I apply that?

Comment: @Ben_Wright, If you have a new question, please [ask it separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). But please make sure it hasn't been asked before.