# Convert DatetimeIndex to datetime.date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to subtract today's date from a column in pandas to get the number of days(as an integer).

I first converted the date's in column(ex: 27-Sep-2018) using `pd.to_datetime`.

`df['Date'] - datetime.datetime.now().date()`

I got the following error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'datetime.date'

I am trying to figure out how to get this to work, also converting the days to integer?

Comment: have you tried `df['Date'].date()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the issue may be due to you subtracting a pandas datetime object from a date object (which does not include the time). You can try this:

```
df['Date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
```

Now doing the calculation: `df['Date_2'] - datetime.datetime.now().date()` should work.

Answer (score 4):

Let's use pandas `Timestamp.now()`:

```
s = pd.Series('27-Sep-2018')

s = pd.to_datetime(s)

(s - pd.Timestamp.now()).dt.days
```

Output:

```
0     15
dtype: int64
```

Note:  The error is stating that you can't subtract object type DatetimeIndex from object 'datetime.date'.  So, use pandas Timestamp to create the same object type as DateTimeIndex.

Comment: Performance comment, [this question from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274356/conversion-of-a-timedelta-to-int-very-slow-in-python/52274596#52274596) seems to demonstrate that `dt.days` doesn't actually *take advantage* of the underlying NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

try to use datetime.strptime() function to convert it.

in your ex='27-Sep-2018' it would look like these:

```
from datetime import datetime
ex='27-Sep-2018'
date = datetime.strptime(ex, '%d-%b-%Y')
```

and then:

```
date.days
```

will store result (type - int)

Answer (score 2):

```py
index[0].to_pydatetime()
```

See here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-datetimeindex-to_pydatetime/