# Pandas: can't convert datetime YYYY-mm-dd to dd-mm-YYYY

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime, series

I have a pandas dataframe with column with dates (datetime64[ns] format)
The dates are listed as yyyy-mm-dd (like 2018-09-12). I want to convert it
to dd-mm-yyyy but what i try doesn't seem to works:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
0    2018-09-12
1    2018-09-12
```

Edit: add example df

```
df.head(3)
        date      nr
0   2018-09-12   144
1   2018-09-12    37
2   2018-09-12    28

df.info()
date   datetime64[ns]
nr     int
```

The 'date' doesn't contain any Nan's or Nat's

Comment: Unfortunately, the example is not complete, so we cannot test it. However, the `format` parameter for `to_datetime` is used to specify the format used for parsing, not the one used for printing the parsed datetime instance.

Comment: Can you explain what you need to complete the example? Do I need to add a example of the dataframe?

Comment: No one know what your original `df` look like or `df['date']`. We can just guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The dates are listed as yyyy-mm-dd (like 2018-09-12).

Yes, but this is **not** how they are stored. What you are seeing is a specific **string representation** of `datetime` objects. Internally, `datetime` values are [stored as integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758140/9209546).

> I want to convert it to dd-mm-yyyy but what i try doesn't seem to
>   works

Correct, because `pd.to_datetime` converts to a `datetime` object. You need to instead convert your series to a series of strings, which will have `object` dtype:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the date parsed with `to_datetime` to a string in the desired representation. The display format you see right now is the default one used for `Datetime` objects:

```
In [10]: frame = {'date': ['2018-09-12', '2016-10-02']}

In [11]: pd.to_datetime(frame['date']).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
Out[11]: Index(['12-09-2018', '02-10-2016'], dtype='object')
```