# Pandas dataframe value changes from datetime to Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I created a datetime variable and when appended into DataFrame, it automatically converted to Timestamp. how can this happen? anyone can some idea on this?

```
mydatetime=datetime.datetime(2019,1,22)
df_test=pd.DataFrame(columns=['datetimecol','value'])
df_test.loc[len(df_test)]=[mydatetime,12.3]
df_test
df_test.datetimecol[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Pandas specializes in vectorised operations facilitated by NumPy arrays.<sup>1</sup> Hence Pandas can store a `datetime` series in a contiguous memory block backed by integer (`int64`) values. In contrast, a list of `datetime.datetime` values will consist of a sequence of pointers to a number of different memory addresses.

Apart from better memory management, `pd.Timestamp` supports the functionality available to `datetime.datetime` objects and, in addition, useful Pandas-specific functionality.

In general, avoid `import datetime` if you can when using Pandas. Not only is it usually unnecessary, but it will also likely be *less* efficient than working directly with `pd.Timestamp` objects.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758140/9209546) for more information on how precisely this works.