# Numpy.minimum with Pandas.Series of Timestamps TypeError: Cannot compare 'Timestamp' with 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I would like to vectorize the computation of the overlap of time intervals using `np.minimum` on `pd.Series`:

```
np.minimum(
    pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:43:00'),
    pd.Series([pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:44:00'), pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:41:00')]))
```

However, this results in the following `TypeError`:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-07083aa6dce1> in <module>()
    1 np.minimum(
    2     pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:43:00'),
----> 3     pd.Series([pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:44:00'), pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:41:00')]))

pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp.__richcmp__()

TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'
```

Using a `np.array` works like a charm (using `.values` not):

```
np.minimum(
    pd.Series([1, pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:43:00')])[1], 
    np.array([pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:44:00'), pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:41:00')]))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do short, instead of using `pd.to_datetime` to create the upper bound, use [`np.datetime64`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

```
s = pd.Series([pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:44:00'), pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:41:00')])
print (np.minimum(s, np.datetime64('2018-01-16 21:43:00')))
0   2018-01-16 21:43:00
1   2018-01-16 21:41:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

or even this `np.minimum(s, pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:43:00').to_datetime64())` works.

To see a bit more: If you have a look at both `dtype` or even the element representation of the two way you create your data, you can see the differences.

```
print (s.values)
array(['2018-01-16T21:44:00.000000000', '2018-01-16T21:41:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
print (np.array([pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:44:00'), pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:41:00')]))
array([Timestamp('2018-01-16 21:44:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-16 21:41:00')],
      dtype=object)
```

One way interesting is to change the type of `s.values` such as:

```
print (np.minimum(s.values.astype('datetime64[s]'), 
                  pd.to_datetime('2018-01-16 21:43:00')))
array([Timestamp('2018-01-16 21:43:00'),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 16, 21, 41)], dtype=object)
```

it works but you can see that one is a `Timestamp` and the other one is `datetime`, it seems that when the type of `s.values` is `datetime[ns]` the comparison is not possible while `datetime64[s]` or even `datetime64[ms]` it does.

Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758140/9274732), it may help.